# express route matching a regex

Tags: regex, express, routes

I am using expressjs and I want to create a route except for all the paths that start with `/api/2`.

This is what I tried

```
app.get(/^((?!\/api\/2).)*$/, home.index)
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Couldn't find much information on how to declare regex routes.

Help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Make a route for that path, then make a catch-all after it.

Comment: makes sense, but I am wondering why the regex doesn't work...

Comment: JavaScript, unfortunately, doesn't support lookbehind assertions, only lookahead.  That's why it doesn't work.